# OpenCMIS 0.9 - Creating custom property

Tags: java, cmis, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I'm trying to create a custom property for my files on my CMIS repository. I am not using Alfresco or other similar extensions (and i can't use it).

I have been looking for information [here](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/properties/index.html) but that code doesn`t work (using versions 0.9, 1.0 and 1.1) and I always get the same error:

```
"Property 'my:project' is not valid for this type or one of the secondary types!"
```

I want to link a custom property (my:project or my:personalId) to the cmis:document type, so I cant`t create a new type or secondary type (which also fails).

How can I do this, using **only the OpenCMIS API** (specially 0.9 version)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The property that you want to link to your document type, has to be present in your Content Model. The cause of the error your are getting, is may be either you have typed it wrong or it does not present there in your model file.

Comment: Did you make sure you're connecting to a CMIS v1.1 endpoint for your server, not a CMIS 1.0 endpoint?